# How can I find the first regex that matches my input in a list of regexes?

Tags: c#, regex

Is there another way to write the following?

```
string input;

var match = Regex.Match(input, @"Type1");

if (!match.Success)
{
  match = Regex.Match(input, @"Type2");
}

if (!match.Success)
{
  match = Regex.Match(input, @"Type3");
}
```

Basically, I want to run my string thru a gammut of expressions and see which one sticks.

Comment: Put the regexes in a list, and then iterate over that list until you hit one.

Comment: `Put the regexes in a list, and then iterate over that list until you hit one.` or write a better regex like `Type1|Type2|Type3`

Comment: @L.B how to figure out which part of the regex succeeded when you combine them? Assuming the regexes are non trivial.

Comment: hmm the code as is, doesn't figure out which match was successful either. So the question text is a bit inconsistent with the code. @rod do you care which of the patterns matched, or do you only care about the `Match` object?

Comment: I only care about the match object, but it would be nice to know if multiple matches occurred.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, `how to figure out which part of the regex succeeded when you combine them?` , for example?

Comment: For example when you have the regex `ab+a` and `ac+a` and want to know which part was successfully matched. If you combine the regex you're only told which part of the target string was matched, but not which pattern was the cause. But since the OP clarified that he's not interested in that, the combining approach is fine. But you still don't learn if multiple matches occurred.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, See this. `var match in Regex.Matches("abba", @"(?<G1>ab+a)|(?<G2>ac+a)")` and the result in `match.Groups["G1"]` and `match.Groups["G2"]`

Answer (score 11):

```
var patterns = new[] { "Type1", "Type2", "Type3" };
Match match;
foreach (string pattern in patterns)
{
    match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
    if (match.Success)
        break;
}
```

or

```
var patterns = new[] { "Type1", "Type2", "Type3" };
var match = patterns
    .Select(p => Regex.Match(input, p))
    .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Success);

// In your original example, match will be the last match if all are
// unsuccessful. I expect this is an accident, but if you want this
// behavior, you can do this instead:
var match = patterns
    .Select(p => Regex.Match(input, p))
    .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Success)
    ?? Regex.Match(input, patterns[patterns.Length - 1]);
```

Because LINQ to Objects uses deferred execution, `Regex.Match` will only be called until a match is found, so you don't have to worry about this approach being too eager.

Comment: I think you'll need `FirstOrDefault` since it's probably not guaranteed that at least one matches.

Comment: One could also create a list of compiled regexes for better performance.

Comment: Technically, the linq way (while probably more what was actually intended) isn't *exactly* the same. In the OP and the first example in this answer `match` will be equal to the last matched set, whether its successful or not. But still a +1.

Comment: Looping over patterns is for those who don't know regex.

Comment: @32bitkid: Ah, you have a point (though it will only be the last matched set **if** all other sets are unsuccessful). I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I would write it like this to avoid executing the Regex match multiple times:

```
        match = Regex.Match(input, @"Type1|Type2|Type3");

        if (match.Success)
        {
            // loop, in case you are matching to multiple occurrences within the input.
            // However, Regex.Match(string, string) will only match to the first occurrence.
            foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
            {
                // if you care to determine which one (Type1, Type2, or Type3) each capture is
                switch (capture.Value)
                {
                    case "Type1":
                        // ...
                        break;
                    case "Type2":
                        // ...
                        break;
                    case "Type3":
                        // ...
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

---

Alternatively, if you have an arbitrary list of patterns that you want to check:

```
        // assumption is that patterns contains a list of valid Regex expressions
        match = Regex.Match(input, string.Join("|", patterns));

        if (match.Success)
        {
            // obviously, only one of these return statements is needed

            // return the first occurrence
            return match.Captures[0].Value;

            // return an IEnumerable<string> of the matched patterns
            return match.Captures.OfType<Capture>().Select(capture => capture.Value);
        }
```

---

Here is another approach that uses named capture groups in order to index each pattern.  when a match is found, we attempt to determine which of the capture groups was matched.

<s>I very much dislike this code due to the repeated unnecessary concatenation of "Pattern" with the index, but I'm not sure how to do this cleaner:</s>

EDIT: I've cleaned up this code a bit by using a dictionary

```
        // assumption is that patterns contains a list of valid Regex expressions
        int i = 0;
        var mapOfGroupNameToPattern = patterns.ToDictionary(pattern => "Pattern" + (i++));

        match = Regex.Match(input, string.Join("|", mapOfGroupNameToPattern.Select(x => "(?<" + x.Key + ">" + x.Value + ")")));

        if (match.Success)
        {
            foreach (var pattern in mapOfGroupNameToPattern)
            {
                if (match.Groups[pattern.Key].Captures.Count > 0)
                {
                    // this is the pattern that was matched
                    return pattern.Value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code only works because the sample regexes don't contain any wildcards. I assume the real regexes aren't that trivial.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - hmm, fair point. I will try to address that possibility.

Comment: If there is an issue with my code or my approach, I'd appreciate opinions. I won't claim this code is excellent, but as far as I'm aware (and from my own testing) it seems to get the job done, and with only one call to Regex.Match at that. Although I'm not sure whether this problem is more efficiently solved by combining patterns into a single regex (as my examples do) or by performing multiple regex matches (as the other answers do). Curious if anyone has an opinion.

Comment: One potential issue is a naming collisions between named groups in the element patterns, and in your outer expression. But that's shouldn't be a problem since the OP defines all of them at compile-time.

Comment: But since the OP clarified his question, that's irrelevant, and your original approach would be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it. It iterates through all the list, BUT you can look a variable number or strings to match without having to write x num of if statements.

```
string input = "Type1";
List<string> stringsToTest = new List<string>() { @"Type1", @"Type2", @"Type3" };

var q = from string t in stringsToTest
        where Regex.IsMatch(input, t)
        select t;

//This way you can get how many strings on the list matched the input   
foreach(string s in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to know which one matches, not only that one matches.